# SDL2 linking doesn't seem to work for the new functions

Tags: linker, mingw, sdl, codeblocks

I've been transitioning to SDL 2 from 1.2 and I seem to have finally fixed all incompatibilities within my code. However, I am still getting some compile errors that appear to be about linking, but I have tried everything I know of to fix the linker directories and don't know what to do now.

Since warnings, the compile directory, the program name, and repeats of the same compiler output line don't matter in this situation, I've omitted warnings, changed the compile directory to "C:\", changed the program name to "program", and removed duplicated compiler output lines.

```
C:\program.program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyRenderer'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyTexture'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_CreateTexture'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_LockTexture'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_UnlockTexture'|
C:\program.o:program.cpp|| undefined reference to `SDL_GetMouseFocus'|
```

I'd think that if it were a problem with including the library then many of the other SDL functions would freak out, but the audio functions, LoadBMP, and LoadWAV seem to be fine.

Is it possible that I am still linking the old SDL 1.2 libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was actually linking the x64 libraries when I was supposed to be linking the i686 libraries. I'm not sure why I can't use the 64-bit ones, but apparently MinGW likes for them to be 32-bit.